# javascript, iframe - navigate/close parent window from iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Good day to all.

I have this setup:

One page with text/whatever, that also includes an iframe (the page in iframe is created by me so I have access to it, I can modify its content).

What I need to do is that when I access a link from the iframe to open it on the mother page (navigate).

Until now I kind of failed to do that so any help would be appreciated.

For any further info just ask.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In all of the links that you want to affect the parent window do something like this:

```
<a href="somthing.html" target="_parent">GO THERE!</a>
```

Or with javascript:

```
<a href="javascript:window.parent.location = 'somthing.html';" >GO SOMEWHERE!</a>
```

Answer (score 5):

If all you need to do is change the parent window's location from inside the iframe, it is very simple:

```
 window.parent.location = 'newWindow.html';
```

Or if you are using a link, just use it's "target" attribute.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the target attribute `<a href="" target="...">`

For all the possible values of target, you can go [here](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/linking/_A_TARGET.html).