# How can I load URL content in main window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using below code to load some content in iFrame.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px;  width:550px; height:280px;" onClick=onStopRecording();>
        <div style="overflow: hidden; margin-top: -100px; margin-left: -25px;"></div>
        <iframe id="exIframe" src="http://example.com" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"  style="height: 280px; border: 0px none; width: 550px; margin-top: -60px; margin-left: -24px;"></iframe>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now when I click the URL inside the iFrame, it needs to redirect to that URL and get loaded in main window itself.

But it is loading inside the iFrame.

Please note that I am using third party site inside the iFrame where I can't have access to edit the code

Could you please help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect parent window from an iframe action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/580669/redirect-parent-window-from-an-iframe-action)

Comment: Is this similar to your issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952927/javascript-iframe-navigate-close-parent-window-from-iframe

Comment: No javascript required, set the `target` property of the `a` element to `_top` in your HTML.

Comment: but to do this I need to get the URL from iFrame right? which is not possible because of cross domain ?

Comment: the URL which I use inside the iFrame is thirdparty site

Answer (score 3):

You need to do it like this:

```
window.top.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
```

Comment: but to do this I need to get the URL from iFrame right? which is not possible because of cross domain ?

Comment: the URL which I use inside the iFrame is thirdparty site

Comment: Doesn't matter AFAIK. As my example, google.com is third party. So if you want to change main page from inside iframe, you can.

Comment: but we cannot capture the URL inside the iFrame?

Comment: Which URL are you talking about?